# mediaelement.js - Show Duration Before Pressing Play

Tags: mediaelement.js

How do I show the duration of an MP3 file in the player when the page loads (before clicking the Play button)? Right now it shows 00:00 until I click play.

My code:

```
<audio id="player2" src="/mp3/myfile.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio> 
<script>$('audio').mediaelementplayer();</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356452/mediaelement-js-how-do-you-set-duration-before-playing-audio/39306961#39306961

Answer (score -1):

```
<audio id="player2" src="/mp3/myfile.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio> 
<script>$('audio').mediaelementplayer({duration:120});</script>
```

Comment: Is it really only possible to pass a static parameter?